# How to mount quasar app to dom after firebase connection is initialized?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, quasar-framework

Hi how do I initialize my quasar app once after I have established a connection to firebase. I need to do this because my route guards checks whether a user is logged in, but if a user refreshes this causes firebase to check whether a current user exists but since it's a async operation it initially returns null. I have previously achieved this using vue where I have done this in my main.js file, but I'm unsure how to do this is quasar boot file.

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import './assets/main.css'

import { authService } from './firebase/config'

let app

authService.onAuthStateChanged(() => {
  if(!app){
    app = createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
  }
})
```

Here inside main.js standard vue app, we wait for Firebase Auth to initialize and only after .onAuthStateChanged() method fires, we create our Vue App.

In an quasar app there is no main.js but instead boot files which run some code before main app starts.

Below is what a standard boot files looks like but I am unsure how to convert my main.js to a executable boot file, seems like some properties are missing like mount, createApp & use.

```
// import something here

// "async" is optional!
// remove it if you don't need it
export default async ({ /* app, router, store */ }) => {
  // something to do
}
```

Comment: Hello, if my answer was helpful you can accept it by clicking the tick icon and upvote by clicking the up arrow icon. [What should I do when someone answers?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) else feel free to ask further queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This got it working.

```
export default async ({ app, router, store }) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const unsubscribe = authService.onAuthStateChanged(() => {
            resolve()
            unsubscribe()
        })
    })
}
```

Here is also a useful article on quasar boot flow https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/boot-files#quasar-app-flow

Comment: export default async ({ app, router, store }) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      auth.authUser = user
      resolve()
      unsubscribe()
    })
  })
}

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you create a [boot file](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/boot-files) for initializing Firebase in a Quasar project.

> Boot files fulfill one special purpose: they run code before the App’s Vue root component is instantiated while giving you access to certain variables, which is required if you need to initialize a library, interfere with Vue Router, inject Vue prototype or inject the root instance of the Vue app.

Create a boot file using the following command:

```
quasar new boot firebase
```

This will create a boot file `/src/boot/firebase.js`

Install Firebase using npm (or yarn) and then add the following code in your boot file:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {...};

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

export const auth = firebase.auth();
```

As mentioned earlier, boot file runs before Vue component is instantiated. Now you can access this instance of Firebase Auth in any component you want.

```
import {auth} from "@/boot/firebase"

auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  //...
})
```

Comment: I'm not asking on how to setup firebase in a boot file, but how to mount app to DOM after the first auth change to persist users on refresh.

Comment: Works for me. But don't forget to add this to quasar.conf.js:
    boot: [
      'firebase'
    ]