# $ Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'uid') at setup - Quasar 2, Firebase 9 Authentication, Vue.js 3, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, quasar

**GOAL:** Render page with user's list on refresh.

**PROBLEM:** On refresh, the page does not catch the user id from Firebase before the page renders.

**ERROR:** Cannot read properties of null (reading 'uid')

How can I get the user ID from Firebase before the page loads to the DOM? It works fine on initial navigation to the List Page, however, when I press refresh it gives the above error. I need the 'uid' to refresh the list of items. This is a simplified version of my code and something I tried below.

**List.vue**

```
...
    ////////// The following line causes error //////////
const itemsRef = collection(db, 'users/' + auth.currentUser.uid + '/items')

onSnapshot(itemsRef, snapshot => {
    let results = []
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        results.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
      })
    items.value = results
})
...
```

I tried:

**List.vue**

```
...
onAuthStateChanged(auth, ( user ) => {
  if (user) {
    const user = auth.currentUser
    const uid = user.uid

    ////////// The following line causes error //////////
    const itemsRef = collection(db, 'users/' + uid + '/items')

    onSnapshot(itemsRef, snapshot => {
      let results = []
      snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        results.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
      })
      items.value = results
    })
  }
})
...
```

I still get the same error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'uid') at setup

Full simplified **List.vue**

```
<template>

  <q-page padding>
    <p>LIST</p>
    <q-list
      v-if="user"
      bordered
      separator
      v-for="item in items"
      :key="item.id"
    >
      <q-item>
        <q-item-section>
          <div class="column">
            <q-item-label
            >{{ item.name }}
            </q-item-label>
          </div>
        </q-item-section>
      </q-item>
    </q-list>
    <q-list v-show="!uid"> Loading ...</q-list>
  </q-page>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { auth, db } from 'src/boot/firebase'
import { collection, onSnapshot } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth"

export default {
  name: "List",
  setup() {
    const user = ref(auth.currentUser)
    const uid = ref(user.value.uid)
    const item = ref({})
    const name = ref('')
    const items = ref([])
    const id = ref(item.id)
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, ( user ) => {
      if (user) {
        user.value = auth.currentUser
        console.log('user.value: ', user.value)
        const uid = user.value.uid
        console.log('uid:', uid)
        console.log('uid.value:',uid.value)

        //    GET ITEMS LIST FROM FIRESTORE
        console.log('BEFORE ITEMS REF')
        const itemsRef = collection(db, 'users/' + uid + '/items')
        console.log('itemsRef: ', itemsRef)
        onSnapshot(itemsRef, snapshot => {
          let results = []
          snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
            results.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
          })
//      UPDATE VALUES
          items.value = results
        })
      }
    })
//
    return {
      item,
      name,
      items,
      user,
      uid,
      id
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: "*How can I get the user ID from firebase before the page loads to the DOM?*" - you can't.  The DOM will almost certainly load before user information is available, and you have no guarantee how quickly that will happen.  You should use an auth state observer to get a callback when the user is known. The documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you for your response! If you didn't notice, I did try that and gave the same link you did :)  I still get the same error. Is there a different way I should do it or a different place I should put it?

Comment: I think you should focus your question on just the one simplest bit of code and explain what doesn't work the way you expect.  Ignore everything else to keep it simple. Right now, you have lots of samples and different errors going on, which conflates the problem.

Comment: Show the one simplest example that doesn't work the way you expect with enough context that anyone can use to reproduce the issue.  Always start with the simplest example and get that to work before trying other things.

Comment: Now, be specific about which line of code causes the problem as you debug it.

Comment: You need to use an auth state observer to get the value of `auth.currentUser.uid`.  It won't be availble until the callback tells you there is a signed in user.  That's what I was trying to say in the first comment.  `auth.currentUser` will not be available until then.

Comment: @DougStevenson - so, 'onAuthStateChanged' does not do that?  How would I do it? Do I need to use Vuex?

Comment: The user object is simply not available until the callback function is invoked.  Use the callback to find the uid.

Comment: @DougStevenson  hi, again. How do I do that?

Comment: Can you share your complete `list.vue` file instead of just that code snippet? We cannot tell when is that being ran or if you are trying to access any user property before user is loaded.

Comment: @Dharmaraj  Yes, how is that? Thank you for taking a look :) Keep in mind this works at first, but not on refresh.

Answer (score 0):

OMHeck!    I found the answer thanks to Sy3d

[How to mount quasar app to dom after firebase connection is initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68381469/how-to-mount-quasar-app-to-dom-after-firebase-connection-is-initialized)

**src/boot/auth.js**

```
import { auth } from 'src/boot/firebase'

export default async ({ app, router, store }) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const unsubscribe = authService.onAuthStateChanged(() => {
            resolve()
            unsubscribe()
        })
    })
}
```